# Add PCI Passthrough device to VMX file VMWARE

Tags: esxi, pci

I have an ESXi 6.0.0 (build 5572656) and am able to add a PCI passthrough device (network card) using the UI. I'd like to be able to include this when deploying a VMX file. The VMX file I'm using works, but not after adding the parts I extracted from the VMX file from the machine I added the PCI passthrough device using the UI.

```
pciPassthru0.id = "00000:009:00.1"
pciPassthru0.deviceId = "0x1521"
pciPassthru0.vendorId = "0x8086"
pciPassthru0.systemId = "59934277-0572-de0c-7556-0025908aca0c"
pciPassthru0.present = "TRUE"
pciPassthru0.pciSlotNumber = "160"
```

I've tried adding just the `id`, `present` and `pciSlotNumber` to the VMX file and the VM won't start. The error is "A general system error occurred". What lines need to be included for this to work?

Comment: I assume you verified the systemid matches the VM your attempting to add the device to manually?

Comment: I tried that at first, but then left systemId out of the VMX. Where can I find the systemId? I'm looking through some VMX files that are working and can't find the system ID. If that's required to do this then I don't know that it's possible since how would I know the systemId ahead of time?